# Which family for glmer to use?

Tags: r, distribution

I´m trying to build my model with the glmer function, but i´m not sure which family should i use, because my data is a ratio most values are 0 and 1s but also many values in between

[image]

Comment: Hi Mari, welcome to SO. In general avoid providing screenshots, you can try and post your data by doing ```dput(data_study_no_nas1)``` and pasting the output in your post

Comment: Also it seems that you are doing the analysis in R, so would help to include the r tag. Lastly, if it is a statistical question, i am afraid it is off topic here. you might need to post it on cross-validated

Comment: Please clarify: Your data does not look like a ratio. It looks like a proportion (because it seems to be bounded by 0 and 1). If so, beta-regression could be appropriate.

Comment: or if you have both the numerator & denominator that were used to calculate the infection rate perhaps Poisson or binomial?